# Upgrading to Rails 4 - Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

I'm hitting some inconsistent behavior while trying to upgrade my project to Rails 4 from 3.2 incrementally with the strong_parameters gem.

In config/application.rb I have the following:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

I'm following the upgrade procedures as spelled out on the gem's [github page](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#migration-path-to-rails-4).

I take a model, strip out attr_accessible and attr_protected, and add `include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` as the first line in the class definition. Then I run rspec to find what tests are red to try to turn them green.

### Class Bar

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  ...
end

let(:bar)  { Bar.create(type: "#{klass_name}") }
```

and

```
let(:bar)  {
  raw_params = { type: "#{klass_name}" }
  params = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_params)
  Bar.create(params.permit(:type))
}
```

both produce

```
 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
   Can't mass-assign protected attributes: type
```

regardless of the value of `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes`

**Problem: This isn't working at all.**

### Class Foo

```
class Foo < Bar
  ...
end
```

For both

```
before :each do
  Foo.create(status: 'active')
end
```

and

```
before :each do
  raw_params = { status: 'active' }
  params = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_params)
  Foo.create(params.permit(:status))
end
```

When `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false`, both turn tests green, and removing .permit(:status) correctly produces

```
 Failure/Error: Foo.create(params)
 ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes:
   ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes
```

When `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`, both produce

```
Failure/Error: Foo.create(params.permit(:status))
     ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
      Can't mass-assign protected attributes: status
```

**Problem: Either both succeed or both fail for either value of whitelist_attributes. For the purposes of iterative testing, I want a situation where traditional mass assignment fails and the updated code succeeds.**

Where am I faltering?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are upgrading to Rails 4 and using `strong_parameters` gem, you should have

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)
```

Secondly, it seems that 'type' is reserved for Rails https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/issues/142, so that's why it's still giving errors even when you have permitted that `type` key.

My solution is to set the `type` through setter method like `bar.type = 'YourType'` when you're about to save it. That will work with no problem.

I hope it'll help.